# Using variable in PHP exec

Tags: php, exec

I want to use my variables in my PHP exec function:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i $audio_input $audio_output');
```

What is the right way of doing this?
I dont want to change the ffmpeg script. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $audio_input $audio_output");
```

But *please*, go read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

#### Replace with double quotes:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $audio_input $audio_output");
```

Check the manual for [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) here.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes like mentioned before or

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$audio_input.' '.$audio_output);
```