# Using variable in php passthru

Tags: php, variables, command, passthru

I would like to put my variables inside my passthru,

```
$cut1 =DNAseq1 
$cut2 = DNAseq2
```

I have already checked this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878259/using-variable-in-php-exec) but didn't find how to proceed

```
echo passthru('sudo docker run my_docker bash -c "-check "' .$cut1.'"  "'.$cut2);
```

but nothing is displayed on the screen but when I wrote directly the DNAseq1:

```
echo passthru('sudo docker run my_docker bash -c "-check ATCG "'.$cut );
```

It works....but only when I wrote one variable not for 2 
 So what is the problem ??

Comment: You're trying to run a command named `-check` in docker. Is there really a command with that name?

Comment: The quoting is a little different in the two commands.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the answer; no it's just a random program in order to check the identity of each dna sequences; I know, I've tried different things, but none of the two variables appear

Comment: It's unusual for program names to begin with `-`.

Comment: Can you show how you would run the program from the shell rather than from PHP?

Comment: It is : sudo docker run my_docker bash -c "/home/prg/soap -check Dnaseq_1 DNAseq_2"

Comment: Why isn't `/home/prg/soap` in your `passthru` command?

Comment: I just wanted to make it easy to understand

Comment: That didn't work, it just confused me since it looked like the problem was that you weren't calling the correct program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo passthru("sudo docker run my_docker bash -c '/home/prg/soap -check $cut1 $cut2'");
```

I've used double quotes around the argument to `passthru()` so I can substitute variables more clearly.